# Node.js async.whilst() is not executing at all

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm just trying to use `async.whilst()` as seen [here](http://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#whilst).

Here is my simple code, taken from their docs:

```
var async = require('async');

console.log('start');
async.whilst(
  function () { return true; },
  function (callback) {
    console.log('iteration');
    callback();
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('end');
  },
);
```

When I run this, the loop doesn't run. Only `start` is printed out.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are returning true, that why the callback for function 1 wasn't called. So you only see the 'start'.
You can find some information below:

```js
    const async = require('async');
    let count = 0;
    const compareVariable = 10;
    console.log('start');
    async.whilst(
        function functionName1(callbackFunction) {
            // perform before each execution of iterFunctionInside, you need a condition(or other related condition) in 2nd params.
            callbackFunction(null, count < compareVariable)
        },
        // this func is called each time when functionName1 invoked
        function iterFunctionInside(callback) {
            // increase counter to compare with compareVariable
            count++;
            console.log('iteration', count);
            // if you want to show like tick time, you can set timeout here or comment out if you dont want
            setTimeout(() => {
                callback(null, count);
            }, 1000)
        },
        function (err, n) {
            console.log('end');
        },
    );
```

Comment: I was using old example code that was just returning `true` for the first function, but later versions of async don't work that way apparently. Always best to read the docs vs someone's outdated sample code in my case.